# Convert a `char *` to UTF-8 in C, or when using xmlwriter?

Tags: c, utf-8, libxml2

I'm using `libxml/xmlwriter` to generate an XML file within a program.

```
const char *s = someCharactersFromSomewhere();
xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute (writer, _xml ("value"), _xml (s));
```

In general I don't have much control over the contents of `s`, so I can't guarantee that it will be well-formatted in UTF-8. Mostly it is, but if not, the XML which is generated will be malformed.

What I'd like to find is a way to convert `s` to valid UTF-8, with any invalid character sequences in `s` replaced with escapes or removed.

Alternatively, if there is an alternative to `xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute`, or some option I can pass in when initializing the XML writer, such that it guarantees that it will always write valid UTF-8, that would be even better.

One more thing to mention is that the solution must work with both Linux and OSX. Ideally writing as little of my own code as possible! :P

Comment: If the string is UTF-8 with the possibility of invalid bytes, [U8_NEXT_OR_FFFD()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/utf8_8h.html#a7dda2b78867c9d648ad5a0f400fdb1b4) from ICU is something I've found useful before for iterating through the codepoints.

Comment: [This](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-encoding.html#xmlCharEncodingHandler) and the following functions appear related – but you need to test yourself if they help you out...

Answer (score 0):

In case the string is encoded in ASCII, then it will always be valid UTF-8 string.
This is because UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII encoding.

See the second paragraph on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Windows primarily works with UTF-16, this means you will have to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 before you pass the string to the XML library.

Comment: Windows: Not necessarily. If you have unicode build enabled and use the wide string API, yes, if not, it uses regional encodings still today (like CP1252)...

Comment: Unfortunately, the string is in this case not valid ASCII (which is why it's also not valid UTF-8). Hence the issue.

Comment: Well to help you I would  have to know where do you get the string from.

Comment: well, let's say that the codepoints of the ASCII character set just match in value to the ascii codes of the same characters.  Windows doesn't use utf-16 encoding.  It uses codepages, all of them based on one byte character sets.  Mainly code page 1250 (iso-8859-1) and 437 (ibm charset)  Only recently has adopted unicode, so recently that 98% of the software still uses codepages.

Comment: You need to write some platform specific code and use some native functions to find the encoding of the text. There is just no way of knowing how the text is encoded without contacting the source of the data. Once you found out what encoding is used by the string, you can use some library to do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 8-bit ascii input then you can simply junk any character code > 127.

If you have some dodgy UTF-8 it is quite easy to parse, but the widechar symbol number that you generate might be out of the unicode range. You can use [`mbrlen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbrlen.3.html) to individually validate each character.

I am describing this using unsigned chars. If you must use signed chars, then >128 means <0.

At its simplest:

```
Until the null byte
 1 If the next byte is 0, then end the loop
 2 If the next byte is < 128 then it is ascii, so keep it
 3 If the next byte is >=128 < 128+64 it is invalid - discard it
 4 If the next byte is >= 128+64 then it is probably a proper UTF-8 lead byte
   call size_t mbrlen(const char *s, size_t n, mbstate_t *ps);
   to see how many bytes to keep 
   if mbrlen says the code is bad (either the lead byte or the trail bytes),
     skip 1 byte. Rule 3 will skip the rest.
```

Even simpler logic just calls mbrlen repeatedly, as it can accept the low ascii range.

You can assume that all the "furniture" of the file (eg xml <>/ symbols, spaces, quotes and newlines) won't be altered by this edit, as they are all valid 7-bit ascii codes.

Comment: `If the next byte is >= 128+64 then it is a proper UTF-8 introducer` is not entirely true. Only byte values in the range `192..247` inclusive are valid for the "introducer", as you call it (most people would more likely call it a "lead byte" instead).

Comment: Yes, "lead byte" is good. It depends what you mean by the valid utf encoding I guess - giving it any more trailing bytes just produces values that are even more out of range. Ok I'll change it to "probably valid". mbrlen() will fail if it is out of range anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a single byte character, while UTF codepoints range from `0` to `0x10FFFFF`, so how do you represent a UTF character in only one byte?

First of all you need a `wchar_t` character.  Those are used with `wprintf(3)` versions of the normal `printf(3)` routines.  If you dig a little on this, you'll see that mapping your UTF codepoints into valid `UTF-8` encoding is straigtforward, based on your `setlocale(3)` settings.  Look at those manual pages referenced, and you'll get an idea of the task you are facing.

There's full support for wide character sets in the C standard... but you have to use it through the internationalization libraries and locales availables.